# H2 equivalent to Oracle's user

Tags: sql, oracle, h2

Is there an H2 equivalent for Oracle's 'user' keyword?  For example, in Oracle, I can do:

```
SELECT USER FROM DUAL;
```

and it will return the user that is logged into the database.
Specifically, I want to default the database user onto a created_by column on a table, i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(
  CREATED_BY Varchar2(100) DEFAULT USER NOT NULL
  ...
)
```

This statement will work in an Oracle database, but H2 throws the exception

> Column "USER" not found;

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't [`USER`](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#user) a function in H2?

```
SELECT USER()
```

will return the current user. Works as expected as a default value for a column:

```
create table MY_TABLE(
  CREATED_BY Varchar2(100) DEFAULT USER() NOT NULL,
  value Varchar2(10)
)
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (value) VALUES ('XXX');
```

As an other user:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (value) VALUES ('YYY');
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Result:

```
CREATED_BY      VALUE  
SA              XXX
SYLVAIN         YYY
```